# Concurrency in Redis for flash sale in distributed system

Tags: spring, concurrency, redis

I Am going to build a system for flash sale which will share the same Redis instance and will run on 15 servers at a time.

So the algorithm of Flash sale will be.

```
Set Max inventory for any product id in Redis 
 using redisTemplate.opsForValue().set(key, 400L);

for every request :
   get current inventory using Long val = redisTemplate.opsForValue().get(key);
    check if it is non zero
     if (val == null || val == 0) {
                            System.out.println("not taking order....");
     } 
else{

put order in kafka 
and decrement using redisTemplate.opsForValue().decrement(key)
}
```

But the problem here is concurrency :
 If I set inventory 400 and test it with 500 request thread,
 Inventory becomes negative,
 If I make function synchronized I cannot manage it in distributed servers.

So what will be the best approach to it?
Note: I can not go for RDBMS and set isolation level because of high request count.

Answer (score 2):

Redis is monothreaded, so running a Lua Script on it is always atomic.
You can define then a Lua script on your Redis instance and running it from your Spring instances.

Your Lua script would just be a sequence of operations to execute against your redis instance (the only one to have the correct value of your stock) and returns the new value for instance or an error if the value is negative.

Your Lua script is basically a Redis transaction, there are other methods to achieve Redis transaction but IMHO Lua is the simplest above all (maybe the least performant, but I have found that in most cases it is fast enough).